# Join two NUMPY arrays by multiple columns

Tags: numpy, join

I have two NUMPY arrays like the following:

```
arr1 = [['a', 1, 23],
['a', 1, 35],
['b', 2, 27],
['b', 3, 98]]

arr2 = [['a', 1, 'g'],
['b', 3, 'h']]
```

I need to join these two arrays by the first columns [0,1] by two ways: by inner join and by left join.

This can be done easily by PANDAS, but I would like to stay in NUMPY array. What I expect is:

1. inner join:

   arr_inner = [['a', 1, 23, 'g'],
   ['a', 1, 35, 'g'],
   ['b', 3, 98, 'h']]
2. left join:

   arr_left = [['a', 1, 23, 'g'],
   ['a', 1, 35, 'g'],
   ['b', 2, 27, nan],
   ['b', 3, 98, 'h']]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Numpy has `concatenate` and related `stack` functions, bu no value based 'join'

Comment: You show lists, not arrays.  `np.array(arr1)` would display differently.       I'd be tempted to write a list approach before trying something with arrays.

Comment: I wouldn't handle join/merge operation with pure numpy. IMHO, NUMpy isn't designed for those ops. I wouldn't even store these arrays as numpy arrays unless it is forced upon.

Comment: The reason I insist NUMPY is because I need to move on to GPU on a Windows system. My understanding is that GPU (Windows) is not friendly to PANDAS.

Comment: Quang Hoang, thanks for your comments. But concatenate and stack functions require exactly same rows of the two arrays.

Comment: hpaulj, you are right. Basically, I want to avoid LIST as it is not fully supported by NUMBA (some features are supported).

Comment: My intention is eventually to use CUPY and NUMBA to use GPU power. As I know, only NUMPY can be helpful for an easy transition on a Windows system.